# Distribution of the sum of squared independent normal random variables

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, normal-distribution

How do I go about finding the the pdf of the statisitc $\sum_i x_i ^2$ such that each $x_i$ is iid from a $N(\sigma , \sigma)$ distribution? I've searched, but cannot find a straightforward answer. I've looked at charts such as [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relationships_among_probability_distributions#/media/File:Relationships_among_some_of_univariate_probability_distributions.jpg) (which I highly recommend reviewing if you have not seen one like it). I've also reviewed [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/656762/distribution-of-the-sum-of-squared-independent-normal-random-variables) answer about the noncentral chi-squared distribution, but it seems to be specifically for iid variables drawn from the distribution $N(0, \sigma^2)$.

Comment: Just to be clear: $X\sim N(\sigma,\sigma)$ means that $X$ has mean $\sigma$ and variance $\sigma$ as usual?

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio yes that is the case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $X_i$ are iid normal with mean $\mu$ and variance $\sigma^2$, then $\sigma^{-2} \sum_{i=1}^n X_i^2$ has noncentral chi-squared distribution with $n$ degrees of freedom and noncentrality parameter $\lambda = n (\mu/\sigma)^2$ (as defined e.g. in [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noncentral_chi-squared_distribution); conventions may sometimes differ).  So what you have is a multiple of a noncentral chi-squared random variable.  If $Y$ has pdf $f_Y$, then $Z = c Y$ (for $c > 0$) has pdf $f_Z(z) = c^{-1} f_Y(z/c)$.

Comment: Thank you @Robert. To clarify, what would $c$ be in the example above?

Comment: Let me use $a$ instead of your $\sigma$, to avoid confusion.  If $\mu = \sigma^2 = a$, then $Y = \sigma^{-2} \sum_{i=1}^n X_i^2$ has the noncentral chi-square distribution with $\lambda = n a$, and your statistic $Z = \sum_{i=1}^n X_i^2 = \sigma^2 Y = a Y$.