# Given bivariate random variable, find the distribution

Tags: probability-distributions, bivariate-distributions

Let $X$ and $Y$ be two independent random variables. If $X$ and $Y$ are both standard normal, then what is the distribution of the random variable $$\frac{1}{2}(X^2+Y^2)$$

Is it right that the answer to this question is $$\frac{1}{2}(X^2+Y^2) \texttt{ ~ }  EXP(1)$$? But how? Thank you very much, any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: You can find the answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/656762/distribution-of-the-sum-of-squared-independent-normal-random-variables), [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/186775/distribution-of-sum-of-squares-of-normals-that-have-mean-zero-but-not-variance-o), [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/89779/sum-of-squares-of-normal-distributions) or [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chi-squared_distribution)

Comment: How did it arrive to an EXP distribution?

Comment: Much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: I add here the reference: Charles M. Grinstead and J. Laurie Snell, *Introduction to Probability*, American Mathematical Society (2003).