# Complex Normal Distribution and the Exponential Distribution

Tags: complex-numbers, stochastic-processes, random-variables

Consider a complex normal variable

$$
z \sim \mathcal{CN}(0,\sigma^2) = X_1 + iX_2
$$

where $X_1,X_2\sim\mathcal{N}\left(0,\frac{\sigma^2}{2}\right)$. Then, the magnitude of this variable is distributed like$^{(a)}$

$$
|z| \sim \sqrt{X_1^2 + X_2^2} = \sqrt{\frac{\sigma^2}{2}\chi_2^2}
$$

where $\chi_2^2$ is the chi-squared distribution of degree 2. We also have$^{(b)}$ that $\chi_2^2 \sim \mathrm{Exp}(1/2)$, meaning we can write the above expression as

$$
|z| \sim \frac{\sigma}{\sqrt{2}}\sqrt{\mathrm{Exp}(1/2)}
$$

I've tried to implement this but can't recover the properties of the complex normal distribution:

```
import numpy as np

variance = 5.0
stddev = np.sqrt(variance)
stddev_half_var = np.sqrt(variance / 2)

a = []
for _ in range(1024):
    a.append(np.random.normal(0, stddev_half_var) + 1j * np.random.normal(0, stddev_half_var))
print("Variance of a: {}".format(np.var(a)))

b = []
for _ in range(1024):
        amp = np.sqrt(variance / 2.0 * np.random.exponential(0.5))
        # Circular symmetry so don't care about phase
        phi = 2 * np.pi * np.random.uniform(0, 1)
        b.append(amp * (np.cos(phi) + 1j * np.sin(phi)))
print("Variance of b: {}".format(np.var(b)))
```

For which I get

```
Variance of a: 5.274641420313699
Variance of b: 1.248419395742529
```

I'm not entirely sure where I've gone wrong here...

**References**

(a) [Distribution of the sum of squared independent normal random variables.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/656762/distribution-of-the-sum-of-squared-independent-normal-random-variables)

(b) https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chi-squared_distribution#Related_distributions